# anatomy of a fwrite

Tags: linux, file, file-io, filesystems

I wrote a small program in C

```
FILE *fp = fopen("/tmp/file", "w+");
char *buf = "hello";
fwrite(buf, 1, strlen(buf), fp);
for(;;);
```

On a shell I use cat to read the contents, the file is empty as fflush is not being called. My question is will it remain like this forever or will at sometime the data will be pushed to disk?

In other words, does the fwrite call crosses the File systems boundary to the VM subsystem, if yes then page daemon should at sometime be invoked which will flush the contents to the file. If not then the data will remain there forever till the file is closed or flushed.

Comment: You forgot to call `fflush(fp)` or `fclose(fp)` before your infinite `for` loop (which you could replace with a `sleep`).

Comment: I purposely did that, my aim is to understand the system here not to write hello in a file :)

Comment: You can `strace` your program to get the actual syscalls it is doing.

Comment: Verified, strace shows open system call but no write system call, so the kernel never knows about the write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each *stdio* `FILE` has an internal buffer (see [setvbuf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/setvbuf.html) for more). The `fwrite` or `fprintf` or `fputs` calls are filling that buffer. It will be written to the file system (using the [write(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html) syscall, executed inside the kernel) only when full or when you call `fflush`.

<sup>You may have line-buffering (e.g. for stdout), then the `write` is triggered when a newline appears in the buffer</sup>

P.S. try to `strace` your program to understand what it is doing.

P.P.S Linux is **free software: you could study the source code** of the [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or of [musl-libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/) -whose source I find easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

fwrite adds buffering on top of the write system call. This buffering takes place in the client-side library (libc), so in your case you can wait forever, because there is no async thread running in libc which does the flush by itself.

Answer (score 3):

FILE* buffering is implemented in libc, so the answer is no: the kernel didn't see your data, and it never will.